# Android: Change strings resource Programmatically

Tags: android, string, resources

Is there a way to do this? For instance, I have a setting in my preferences that can convert between metric and standard units of measurement and when the user changes this I would like to update a few strings to change some labels around within my app.

Comment: Please share your code.. As far as I have understood your question this is easily achievable.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can update the label on TextView or anything similar.

- Get the updated string using `update_str = Context.getResources().getString (R.string.update_identifier)`
- Update the label using `((TextView)findViewById (R.id.textview)).setText (updated_str)`

Answer (score 9):

You may use following instructions to fetch saved labels from strings.xml file and show them accordingly at some 'if statement' which could check your

`pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())
        .getString("conversion_mode", "");`

```
String string = getString(R.string.update_identifier);
```

or

```
getResources().getString (R.string.update_identifier)
```

would do the best

`getString(int)` or `getText(int)` may be used to retrieve a string. 
Please note `getText(int)` will retain **any rich text** styling applied to the string.

Find the [Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)